# What could be wrong if neutral has power?

Tags: switches

I tried to connect a smart switch to my exhaust fan, and probably connected the wires wrong the first time.

Now, I find that with only the red wire connected to the switch, the black wire also shows power, as in the picture below. (And the fan doesn't turn on)

What could have gone wrong?
[image]

Comment: how do you know that there is power in that wire? ... did you measure the voltage with a load connected?

Comment: @jsotola No. As shown in the picture, I used a tester. The tester glows if there is power at the point where it touches

Comment: Which wires were connected to the old fan switch?  What colors are they and how are they grouped into cables?

Comment: the tester could be glowing from induced voltage ... I would not trust the indication in either way ... `light` does not necessarily mean `hot`, and `no light` does not necessarily mean `not hot`

Comment: @harper-reinstateukraine The old switch had the black wire from the fan going to its neutral and red going to load. In the picture, that exposed black wire is coming directly from the fan, unconnected to anything in between. The red from the fan is connected to the output load port of the smart switch. The other vertical pair of red/black comes from the old physical switch and goes into the input power/neutral ports of the smart switch.

Comment: Is that a neon bulb in the tester? You don't need a "complete" circuit to make a neon bulb to glow. Just the capacitance between your body and ground allows enough current—hundreds, or maybe just tens of microamperes—to get a weak glow from the bulb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the fan schematic with a standard switch.

[image]

The only difference with a smart switch is the additional neutral connection.

[image]

Please recheck and rewire.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked when I connected that black dangling wire to the neutral input feed of the smart switch

Comment: Anytime, androidguy! That's good.